# Does a PWA's root file have to be index.html?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Can a PWA have e.g. indexPWA.html as it's root file, or does it always have to be index.html?

I've been using indexPWA.html for testing but when I installed it as a PWA the installed PWA is loading my index.html code, not indexPWA.html. Just wanted to check here if it will always load indext.html as default before I go down too many testing rabbitholes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the file can be something other than index.html.
Do you have indexPWA.html set as your [start_url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url) ?

Comment: Yes - thank you. The issue was that my javascript files weren't updating - regardless the web-app was loading the correct js files, when I installed the web-app as a PWA it would only load the old js files, even after service worker updates. I've gone back to adding version query strings to the end of my js inclusions in the indexPWA.html file and it seems to have solved the issue e.g. js/pwa/js02.js?v=27